# How to group some cells inside a tr and give that group an id for ajax manipulation

Tags: html

I am using `<tbody>` tag to group some cells in a table so that I can manipulate them using ajax. Here is the code below:

```
<tr>
<tbody id="<%=author.AUT_ID%>">
<td><%= author.AUT_FNAME %></td>
<td><%= author.AUT_SURNAME %></td>
</tbody>
<td>more data </td>
<td>more data </td>
<tr>
```

The problem with the above is that the `<tbody>` tag breaks the row into two such that the cells below are displayed in one row and the rest of the cells in another row.

```
<td><%= author.AUT_FNAME %></td> 
<td><%= author.AUT_SURNAME %></td>
```

How can I group some cells indie a row and give that group an id so that I can manipulate it using ajax?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TBODY` must be a direct child of `TABLE`, you can't use inside a row:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/tbody

Comment: How do I group some cells inside a row then? Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: The row is the group of several cells; if just want to style them similarly, you could use CSS classes.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

```
<tbody id="<%=author.AUT_ID%>">
  <tr>
    <td><%= author.AUT_FNAME %></td>
    <td><%= author.AUT_SURNAME %></td>

    <td>more data </td>
    <td>more data </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I need to update only the first 2 td, that's why I need to group it and assign that group an id

Comment: maybe assign them the same class? `<td class="<%=author.AUT_ID%>"><%= author.AUT_FNAME %></td>
    <td class="<%=author.AUT_ID%>"><%= author.AUT_SURNAME %></td>`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you just apply classes to those cells you want to work with.  That would give you a convenient handle for working with them in javascript.